# JavaCV Convert Int Array to Gray Mat

Tags: android, opencv, javacv, yuv

I'm trying to do the most basic of things using JavaCV on Android but still failing.

I want to convert yuv byte[] array received from Camera.PreviewCallback OnPreview into grayscale Mat for further processing.

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

  /* Extract grayscale from yuv */
  ByteBuffer gray = ByteBuffer.allocate(data.length * 4);
  IntBuffer intBuffer = gray.asIntBuffer();

  int p;
  int size = width*height;
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        p = data[i] & 0xFF;
        intBuffer.put(0xff000000 | p<<16 | p<<8 | p);
  }

  Mat g = new Mat(height,width,CV_8UC3);
  byte test[] = gray.array();
  g.data().put(test);  /* crashes here */
```

In my debug inspection it seems that it crashes because of lack of memory.  It doesn't give any error tracke.  Just a message like this

> A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xa0c6a000 in
>   tid 5475 (com.aztech.jcv)

I have tried CV_8UC1 but it still fails.  The issue is probably with memory mismatch.  Pls can someone suggest a working alternative.  Using inbuilt `cvCvtColor` doesn't decode properly - it gives an all black mat with strange lines.

Comment: did you verify that product of height, width and channels(3)=byte array(test) length?

Comment: they are not the same.  but i don't know how to make them the same.